# Finding eigenvalues of indefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = M_2x2(R). Let T: V to V be defined by T(a,b,c,d) = (d,b,c,a). Find the eigenvalues of T and a basis B of V so that [T]_B is a diagonal matrix.

I find the only eigenvalue to be 0. In this case, is the basis just going to be any possible basis as 0 is an eigenvalue to every vector?

The fact that we are using variables here kind of make things unclear.

Thank you.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea that this exercise might be trying to teach you is that eigenvalues are independent of any basis you choose.

So let's choose a basis, write down the matrix of $T$ in that basis and then compute the eigenvalues using the usual method. Why not choose the standard basis $b_1 = \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}, 
b_2 = \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array},
b_3 = \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{array},
b_4 = \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}$. In this basis the matrix $M_T \in M_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb R)$ of $T$ is 
$$ M_T = \begin{array}{cccc} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}$$

$$ \mathrm{det}(M_T - I\lambda )= -\lambda \cdot \left | \begin{array}{ccc}  
 1-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\lambda 
\end{array} \right | + 0 \cdot \left | \begin{array}{ccc}  
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\lambda 
\end{array} \right |  + 0 \cdot \left | \begin{array}{ccc}  
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\lambda 
\end{array} \right | + 1 \cdot \left | \begin{array}{ccc}  
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1-\lambda & 0 
\end{array} \right | $$

$$ =-\lambda (1-\lambda)^2 (-\lambda) +  (1-\lambda)(0-(1-\lambda))= \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^2 - (1-\lambda)^2 = p(\lambda)$$

Check that $p(1) = 0$. Also check that $p(-1) = 0$. So you found two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2=-1$.

It should be not difficult to compute the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: Just for confirmation, I get eigenspace of 1 as 3 dimensional with basis: (0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(1,0,0,1) and one-dimensional eigenspace of -1 with basis (-1,1,1,1). Is this correct?

Comment: @mch The first space is correct. The second space [not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+of+%5B%5B+0+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+1+%5D%2C++%5B0+%2C+1+%2C+0+%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0+%2C+0+%2C+1+%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B1+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+0%5D++%5D).

Answer (score 0):

This linear map is certainly invertible, so $0$ will not be an eigenvalue. Write down the 4 equations for $a,b,c,d$ you get when you say $T(X) = \lambda X$, for $X=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}$.

As a further hint, I will tell you that there are two eigenvalues. One eigenspace is $1$-dimensional and the other is $3$-dimensional.